# java.io.FileNotFoundException thrown on certain URLs in a list (BingSearch API)

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, bing-api

I've been trying to get the Bing Search API to work in my android project for a while now, and I've been mostly successful. However, a few of the queries that I pass the API give me a `java.io.FileNotFoundException`. I cannot figure out why, as I've tested those query values in Postman, and the data comes in as expected. Here is my BingSearch class as well as the relevant code snippet:

**Call To BingSearch API**

```
public void getUrls() {
    try {
        ....
            try {
                //song format: "Song, Artist"
                idRuntimes.add(new BingSearch.GetSearch().execute(songs.get(i)).get());
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        ...

}
```

**BingSearch Class**

```
public class BingSearch {

    static String subscriptionKey = "subscription_key";

    // Verify the endpoint URI.  At this writing, only one endpoint is used for Bing
    // search APIs.  In the future, regional endpoints may be available.  If you
    // encounter unexpected authorization errors, double-check this value against
    // the endpoint for your Bing Web search instance in your Azure dashboard.
    static String host = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com";
    static String path = "/bing/v7.0/videos/search";

    static String searchTerm;

    static String videoId, runtime;
    private static String TAG = "BingSearch";

    public BingSearch(String term) {
        searchTerm = term.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9%\\[\\]]", "");

        try {
            String complete = new GetSearch().execute().get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static SearchResults SearchVideos (String searchQuery) throws Exception {
        // construct URL of search request (endpoint + query string)
        URL url = new URL(host + path + "?q=" +  URLEncoder.encode(searchQuery, "UTF-8"));
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

        // receive JSON body
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        String response = new Scanner(stream).useDelimiter("\\A").next();

        // construct result object for return
        SearchResults results = new SearchResults(new HashMap<>(), response);

        // extract Bing-related HTTP headers
        Map<String, List<String>> headers = connection.getHeaderFields();
        for (String header : headers.keySet()) {
            if (header == null) continue;      // may have null key
            if (header.startsWith("BingAPIs-") || header.startsWith("X-MSEdge-")) {
                results.relevantHeaders.put(header, headers.get(header).get(0));
            }
        }

        stream.close();
        return results;
    }

    // pretty-printer for JSON; uses GSON parser to parse and re-serialize
    public static String prettify(String json_text) {
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject json = parser.parse(json_text).getAsJsonObject();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        return gson.toJson(json);
    }

    public static class GetSearch extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                SearchResults result = SearchVideos(params[0]);

                //Log.d("BING", "\nRelevant HTTP Headers:\n");
                for (String header : result.relevantHeaders.keySet())
                    Log.d("BING", header + ": " + result.relevantHeaders.get(header));

                //Log.d("BING", "\nJSON Response:\n");
                Log.d("BING", prettify(result.jsonResponse));

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String jsonOutput = result.jsonResponse;
                Type listType = new TypeToken<VideoResults>(){}.getType();
                VideoResults results = gson.fromJson(jsonOutput, listType);
                videoId = results.getValue().get(0).getContentUrl();
                runtime = results.getValue().get(0).getDuration();

                Log.d("SearchResult: " + params[0], videoId + " | " + runtime);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Error-" + TAG, e.toString());
            }
            return videoId + "," + runtime;
        }
    }
}

// Container class for search results encapsulates relevant headers and JSON data
class SearchResults{
    HashMap<String, String> relevantHeaders;
    String jsonResponse;
    SearchResults(HashMap<String, String> headers, String json) {
        relevantHeaders = headers;
        jsonResponse = json;
    }
}
```

**ERRORS *(only 2 out of a list of 7 queries)***

```
D/Error-BingSearch: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/videos/search?q=House+In+LA%2C+Jungle
D/Error-BingSearch: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/videos/search?q=Cherry%2C+Jungle
```

Comment: have you found the problem with this? or a solution?